# Correct way to run scripts in automated, unattended Windows installation

Tags: windows, scripting, automation, sysprep, answer-file

I have some custom scripts that I have written to customise Windows 10 such as removing bloatware and setting file explorer options via Registry Editor that I use to apply to all users and/or the system.

I have created a `autounattend.xml` Answer File with some simple parameters such as formatting the disk, creating partitions and selecting the version of Windows to install etc and then using the `reseal` parameter to log the computer into Audit Mode automatically after the initial installation and bypassing the OOBE screen.

My scripts have all been tested in Audit Mode (CTRL, SHIFT + F3 from the OOBE screen) and they work perfectly fine for any proceeding user that uses the system once it's in normal working order. Additionally, I use an `unattend.xml` file located in `$OEM$\$$\System32\Sysprep` within the installation media to finish the installation after I leave Sysprep and restart the computer. This sets up a new local administration account and password that logs automatically into the desktop. Essentially I have two unattend Answer Files split into two parts so I'm not actually  sure if this is the correct way of doing it, but it seems to work well.

I would now like to automate the installation completely so that the scripts I currently manually run in Audit Mode execute without any user intervention. In Windows System Image Manager there is the `RunAsynchronousCommand` component found under `amd64_Microsoft-Windows-Deployment_10.0.19041.1_neutral` which can only be added to `Pass 6 auditUser`. Within the `$OEM$` folder on my installation media is the following directory structure `$1\Scripts`, and this contains various Batch and PowerShell scripts. I would like to point the path parameter of `RunAsynchronousCommand` to the Scripts folder the `$OEM$` folder creates but nothing ever seems to work.

Because I'm using two-part Answer Files, should I be placing `RunAsynchronousCommand` into my `autounattend.xml` or `unattend.xml` Answer File?

With everything all working, do I need to remove any of the `Reseal` properties from the Answer File?

Below are the contents of my two Answer Files located on my installation media:

**/autounattend.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <EnableNetwork>false</EnableNetwork>
            <ImageInstall>
                <OSImage>
                    <InstallFrom>
                        <MetaData wcm:action="add">
                            <Key>/IMAGE/NAME</Key>
                            <Value>Windows 10 Pro</Value>
                        </MetaData>
                    </InstallFrom>
                    <WillShowUI>Always</WillShowUI>
                </OSImage>
            </ImageInstall>
            <UserData>
                <ProductKey>
                    <WillShowUI>Always</WillShowUI>
                    <Key />
                </ProductKey>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
            </UserData>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <UILanguage>en-gb</UILanguage>
                <WillShowUI>Always</WillShowUI>
            </SetupUILanguage>
            <InputLocale>en-gb</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-gb</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguageFallback>en-us</UILanguageFallback>
            <UILanguage>en-gb</UILanguage>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Reseal>
                <Mode>Audit</Mode>
            </Reseal>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

**$OEM$/$$/System32/Sysprep/Unattend.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoLogon>
                <Password>
                    <Value>cABhAHMAcwB3AG8AcgBkAFAAYQBzAHMAdwBvAHIAZAA=</Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </Password>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                <LogonCount>1</LogonCount>
                <Username>LocalAdmin</Username>
            </AutoLogon>
            <UserAccounts>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Password>
                            <Value>cABhAHMAcwB3AG8AcgBkAFAAYQBzAHMAdwBvAHIAZAA=</Value>
                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Name>LocalAdmin</Name>
                        <Group>Administrators</Group>
                        <DisplayName></DisplayName>
                        <Description>Local adminstrator stored on the system drive</Description>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
            <OOBE>
                <HideOnlineAccountScreens>true</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideOEMRegistrationScreen>true</HideOEMRegistrationScreen>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <ProtectYourPC>3</ProtectYourPC>
                <HideLocalAccountScreen>true</HideLocalAccountScreen>
                <SkipUserOOBE>true</SkipUserOOBE>
                <SkipMachineOOBE>true</SkipMachineOOBE>
            </OOBE>
            <BluetoothTaskbarIconEnabled>true</BluetoothTaskbarIconEnabled>
            <DesktopOptimization>
                <ShowWindowsStoreAppsOnTaskbar>false</ShowWindowsStoreAppsOnTaskbar>
                <GoToDesktopOnSignIn>true</GoToDesktopOnSignIn>
            </DesktopOptimization>
            <StartTiles>
                <PromoteOEMTiles>false</PromoteOEMTiles>
            </StartTiles>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```